# Why is my array only returning the last value in a loop?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, implode

I have the following code which is meant to cycle through names submitted on a form:

```
$row_count = count($_POST['name']);
if ($row_count > 0) {

  mysql_select_db($database, $connection);
  $name = array();
  $workshop = array();

  for($i = 0; $i < $row_count; $i++) {
    // variable sanitation...
    $name[i] = mysql_real_escape_string(ucwords($_POST['name'][$i]));
    $workshop[i] = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['workshop'][$i]);
    }
  $names = "('".implode("','",$name)."')";
.....etc
```

For some reason `$names` is only returning the last name submitted on the form, rather than all of the names.  Could someone help me get this working correctly?

Thanks,

Nick

Answer (score 6, accepted):

problem is here

```
$name[i] = 
$workshop[i] =
```

solution:

```
$name[$i] = 
$workshop[$i] =
```

now your code is working in this way:

```
$name["i"] = 
$workshop["i"] =
```

so you have only one element in `$name`, `$workshop` arrays. (last from loop)